# stop applying css selector for one element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to prevent this CSS selector from being applied to all elements in the page:

```
input {
    color:red;
}
```

This will make the text red for `<input>`s of every type, but I want to exclude one input from this without changing the selector or style of this CSS rule. The element should have the default style (how it is when you have no css on the page).

Comment: You will have to override those styles or change your selector to exclude that element. There's really no other way of doing it.

Comment: @Kuf: I'm not sure what you mean. What about it?

Comment: @Blender sorry, didn't understood you right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the not selector. Since an input field should have a name, you could exclude it by using:

```
input:not([name="exludeme"]) { }
```

This method won't work in IE8 and earlier versions. To support ie7 and ie8 too, you could use the attribute selector. In this case you have to reset the field:

```
input[name="exludeme"] { /*add all your reset styles here*/ }
```

Comment: IE8 and earlier do not support the :not selector.

Comment: well I think that still in 2013 your comment should be part of your answer

Answer (score 3):

add an id for the different one and apply it just for him, and to make sure that no other css will overwrite the css you choose use [!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)

**html**:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" id="diff"></div>
```

**css**:

```
div.box {
  background-color:red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position: relative;
}

#diff{
  background-color:black  !important ;
}
```

check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/y32Wv/

**note:** `!important` is optional, depends on the selector position inside the file, but in cases where it might be overwrite by other css rule (for example if someone change the order of the css rules) it will stop working right, and `!important` will prevent it from happening.